# I can't make my player shoot on Pygame because it says : 'float' object has no attribute '__getitem__'

Tags: python-2.7, pygame

Well. All I wanted is to shoot some bullets in my game. I tried so hard but I can't!

First I store the bullets angle and position in bullets_array's list. Second, I gave to it velocity by 'sin' and 'cos' and I limited its motion on 640px and 480px in a loop. Then I displayed it on player_x, player_y.

It was supposed to start on player_x, player_y, to walk by cos and sin laws and to destroy on the bordelines of the screen.

But it is shown the following sentence:

> line 53
>   vel_x = math.cos(bullet[0])*10
>  TypeError: 'float' object has no
>   attribute '**getitem**'

Here is the code.

```
#
# Title: Shoot The Zombies
# Author(s): John Redbeard, ("http://john-redbeard.tumblr.com/")
# 

import pygame
from pygame.locals import *
import math

    # Initiate Pygame
pygame.init()
width, height = 640, 480
screen=pygame.display.set_mode((width, height))
pygame.display.set_caption("Shoot the Zombies")
fps = 60
fpsclock = pygame.time.Clock()

    # Load images
player = pygame.image.load("images/player.png")
player_x = 100
player_y = 100
posplayer_x = 0
posplayer_y = 0

grass = pygame.image.load("images/grass.png")

bullet = pygame.image.load("images/bullet.png")
bullets_array = []

target = pygame.image.load("images/target.png")

    # Main Loop Game
while True:

    pygame.mouse.set_visible(False)

    screen.fill(False)

    # Load on screen the grass in isometric way
    for x in range(width/grass.get_width()+1):
        for y in range(height/grass.get_height()+1):
            screen.blit(grass,(x*100,y*100))

    # Load on screen the rotated-positioned-player
    mouse_position = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
    angle = math.atan2(mouse_position[0] - player_x, mouse_position[1] - player_y)
    player_rotate = pygame.transform.rotate(player, 360+angle*57.29)
    player_position = (player_x - player_rotate.get_rect().width/2, player_y - player_rotate.get_rect().height/2)
    screen.blit(player_rotate, player_position)

    # load on screen the rotated-posioted-bullets
    for bullet in bullets_array:
        vel_x = math.cos(bullet[0])*10
        vel_y = math.sin(bullet[1])*10
        bullet[0] += vel_x
        bullet[1] += vel_y
        if bullet[0] >640 or bullet[1] > 480:
            bullets_array.remove(bullet)
        bullet1 = pygame.transform.rotate(bullet, 360+angle*57.29)
        screen.blit(bullet1, (player_x, player_y))

    # Load on screen the target
    screen.blit(target, (mouse_position))

    # Display window
    pygame.display.flip()

    # Run events
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type==pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit() 
            exit(False)

    # Event: W/A/S/D (Keyboard) moving player
        elif event.type == KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == K_w:
                posplayer_y -= 3
            elif event.key == K_a:
                posplayer_x -= 3
            elif event.key == K_s:
                posplayer_y += 3
            elif event.key == K_d:
                posplayer_x += 3

        elif event.type == KEYUP:
            if event.key == K_w:
                posplayer_y = 0
            elif event.key == K_a:
                posplayer_x = 0
            elif event.key == K_s:
                posplayer_y= 0
            elif event.key == K_d:
                posplayer_x = 0

    # Event: Mouse click shoot the bullet
        elif event.type == MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            bullets_array.append(math.atan2(mouse_position[0] - player_x, mouse_position[1] - player_y))

    player_x += posplayer_x
    player_y +=posplayer_y

    fpsclock.tick(fps)
```

Comment: So first "bullet' is a PNG file. Then it's an item in an array of floats, then you take that float, and try to use it as a two element array bullet[0] and bullet[1]?

Answer (score 3):

You added `float` values to `bullets_array`:

```
bullets_array.append(math.atan2(mouse_position[0] - player_x, mouse_position[1] - player_y))
```

That's just **one** [`math.atan2()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/math.html#math.atan2) call; it produces one floating point value.

You then on expect there to be **two** values:

```
for bullet in bullets_array:
    vel_x = math.cos(bullet[0])*10
    vel_y = math.sin(bullet[1])*10
```

You cannot index a floating point value.

If you expected there to be two values, you'll have to create a tuple with two floats, not add just the one float. You certainly did not

> store the bullets angle and position in bullets_array's list